# vba how to add same values for multiple combo box?

Tags: vba

**I'm trying to add a list of numbers to multiple combo boxes at the same time with an easy way**
I tried to use (And) but it's not working

```
With Me.ComboBox10 and Me.ComboBox11
   
   .AddItem "0%"
   .AddItem "10%"
   .AddItem "20%"
   .AddItem "30%" ' and so on.....
   
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a different approach as `With Me.ComboBox10 and Me.ComboBox11` is not valid.

I asssume the ComboBoxes are on a Userform otherwise you have to adjust the code. But the approach does not change.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim vDat As Variant
    ReDim vDat(0 To 5)
    vDat(0) = "0%"
    vDat(1) = "10%"
    vDat(2) = "20%"
    vDat(3) = "30%"
    vDat(4) = "40%"
    vDat(5) = "50%"
    
    Dim sngControl As MSForms.Control
    For Each sngControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(sngControl) = "ComboBox" Then
            sngControl.List = vDat
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim v, ctrl As Control
    v = Array("0%", "10%", "20%", "30%")
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
            If ctrl.Name = "ComboBox1" Or ctrl.Name = "ComboBox3" Then ctrl.List = v
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the fundmental difference to my approach?

Comment: I didn't see your answer when I was posting my code. The codes are nearly the same. The only difference is that I limited the combo boxes to fill.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not realize that you answered just a minute later than me.